# Is it possible to do URL rewrite with Amazon AWS ALB with multiple listener rules?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-application-load-balancer

Is it possible to rewrite the URI in AWS ALB before it can be forwarded to Target group(EC2 instance)?
e.g. Request URL is https://dumydomain.com/home/test.asp

```
IF requested URI contains "test.asp" THEN  
Forward request to Target Group A listening on port 2334 with URI /anotherhome/anotherhome/test.asp
```

Another related question, how can I achieve conditional Forward to different target groups? e.g. in above Listener, I want to add another condition i.e.

```
IF requested URI contains "anothertest.asp" THEN   
Forward request to Target Group B listening on port 2336 with URI /home/anotherh/anothertest.asp
```

Comment: Have you found an answer to this?

Comment: No AWS ALB does not support it, but I managed get around it by writing IIS Rewrite rules and also rearranging my application in IIS.